# CSS classes don't change with the attribute selector

Tags: html, css

My html is linked to the right CSS file and everything and when I point any other element to change color it workes but everytime I deal with classes even when I put .class {color: red;} it doesn't work and for the span[yes]{color: purple;} as well.Is it maybe an outdated CSS, something I need to update?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>

        <head>
        <title>Css for bigginers</title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Sandbox/syntax.css">     
        </head>



        <body>
                <div>

                    <span >WHats poppin</span>
                    <span class= "class">yo Im a span tag</span>
                    <span class= "deck">yo<strong>Im a span tag</strong> </span>
                    <span class= "deck">yo Im a span tag</span>
                    <span class= "yes">yo Im a span tag</span>

                    <a href = "#"> im a spanner</a>

                    <p>This is good</p>
                    <p>The world is beutiful</p>
                    <p class="test">I know tell me about it</p>
                </div> 
        </body>

    </html>

    /***** CSS FILE *****/
    span[yes]{
        color: purple;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you refer to a class. To refer to a class, you must do it like this:

```css
.yes{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class= "yes">yo Im a span tag</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use span.class and span.yes instead of span[yes]. A good practice is not to name the class as class or span or any any keywords used in html or css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

By `span[yes]` you are addressing to spans that have `yes` attribute. Instead use

```
.deck{
  color: red;
}
```

where `.deck` is the name of the class you set in the html element:

```
<span class= "deck"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, `span[yes]` means *a `<span>` element which has the attribute `yes`*, which is obviously not the case in your code. Either `span.[class="yes"]` or the shorthand `span.yes` will work. See the chapter [Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html) in the CSS specification.